# Linq`s Intersect does not call GetHashCode

Tags: c#, linq

```
var resultList = list1.Intersect<XElement>(list2, new XElementComparer());
```

Why is the GetHashCode method of my XElementComparer never called?

When I check the content of the resultList I see:

```
System.Exeception object to set to an instance of an object
```

Both my lists have XElements. What do I wrong?

Comment: It would help to add your implementation of `XElementComparer`

Comment: How do you know it's not calling `GetHashCode`?  It sounds like it's not even working in the first place...

Comment: How do you "check the content of the resultList"? And can you provide a stack trace in the exception you get when doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Intersect` extension method returns an `IEnumerable<>`, but does not actually perform the intersection until you begin enumerating it (e.g. do a `foreach`, call `.ToList()` etc.). As such, I wouldn't expect any of the methods on your comparer to be called based on the snippet you've given, since you aren't enumerating the result.

Comment: Doesn't _When I check the content of the resultList_ imply enumerating the result?

Comment: @AustinSalonen - Yes, but if the OP is checking whether GetHashCode is called by putting a breakpoint on it, and "check[ing] the content of the resultList" is via a watch/debugger tooltip or similar debugger functionality, this would cause evaluation without the breakpoints being hit. It's perhaps a stretch but based solely on the *code* presented no evaluation is occurring.

Comment: @Iridium finally at home. Yes I should foreach the resultList :P

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that it is calling your implementation of `GetHashCode` *and* that implementation (or `Equals`) is throwing a NullReferenceException. **The only way we can really answer your question is for you to include the code for `XElementComparer`.**

I ran a quick test that yield this output:

> Equals count = 1; GetHashCode count = 6

```
[Test]
public void X()
{
    var list1 = new List<Alpha> {new Alpha {Bravo = 1}, new Alpha {Bravo = 1}, new Alpha {Bravo = 2}};
    var list2 = new List<Alpha> { new Alpha { Bravo = 1 }, new Alpha { Bravo = 3 }, new Alpha { Bravo = 5 } };

    var alphaComparer = new AlphaComparer();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, list1.Intersect(list2, alphaComparer).Count());
    Console.WriteLine("Equals count = {0}; GetHashCode count = {1}", alphaComparer.EqualsCallCount, alphaComparer.GetHashCodeCallCount);
}

class Alpha
{
    public int Bravo { get; set; }
}

class AlphaComparer : IEqualityComparer<Alpha>
{
    public int EqualsCallCount { get; private set; }
    public int GetHashCodeCallCount { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(Alpha x, Alpha y)
    {
        EqualsCallCount += 1;
        return x.Bravo.Equals(y.Bravo);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Alpha obj)
    {
        GetHashCodeCallCount += 1;
        return obj.Bravo.GetHashCode();
    }
```